# List of NSException derived classes or exception names?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa, exception

I've been through [Introduction to Exception Programming Topics for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html). Under [Throwing Exceptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/RaisingExceptions.html), there is one exception name shown: `FileNotFoundException`:

```
NSException *e = [NSException
    exceptionWithName:@"FileNotFoundException"
               reason:@"File Not Found on System"
             userInfo:nil];

@throw e;
```

However, the [Predefined Exceptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Concepts/PredefinedExceptions.html) page lists about 10 exceptions and `FileNotFoundException` is not listed.

Where can I find a list of common or expected exceptions and names?

Comment: [It says "_The following example shows how you throw an exception_"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/RaisingExceptions.html) so it is just an *example*, not that it is a predefined exception.

Comment: Thanks Pang. Java, C#, and a number of other languages have that exception. So does the example show how to throw an exception that does no exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's weird, these are the only constants defined in NSExcpetion.h that I see:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSGenericException;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSRangeException;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSInvalidArgumentException;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSInternalInconsistencyException;

FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSMallocException;

FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSObjectInaccessibleException;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSObjectNotAvailableException;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSDestinationInvalidException;

FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSPortTimeoutException;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSInvalidSendPortException;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSInvalidReceivePortException;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSPortSendException;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSPortReceiveException;

FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSOldStyleException;
```

Answer (score 2):

The exception `FileNotFoundException` shown in that particular example is not a predefined exception. All predefined exceptions begin with prefix **NS**, like `NSRangeException` etc. Hence you cannot see it listed under the predefined list of exceptions.

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Concepts/PredefinedExceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000057-BCIGHECA)

> Note that all predefined exceptions begin with the prefix "NS", so you should avoid using the same prefix when creating new exception names.

`FileNotFoundException` is custom exception, which needs to be raised and handled by the developer for custom error conditions. It is recommended that all custom exception should avoid using the prefix **NS**.

As mentioned by pfrank in his answer, list of predefined exceptions can be [found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-CJBGDEAB)

```
extern NSString *NSGenericException;
extern NSString *NSRangeException;
extern NSString *NSInvalidArgumentException;
extern NSString *NSInternalInconsistencyException;
extern NSString *NSMallocException;
extern NSString *NSObjectInaccessibleException;
extern NSString *NSObjectNotAvailableException;
extern NSString *NSDestinationInvalidException;
extern NSString *NSPortTimeoutException;
extern NSString *NSInvalidSendPortException;
extern NSString *NSInvalidReceivePortException;
extern NSString *NSPortSendException;
extern NSString *NSPortReceiveException;
extern NSString *NSOldStyleException;
```

Hope that helps!